# Handling UITableView Rotation with Auto Layout

Tags: autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a table view that is created programmatically in my view controller:

```swift
/// Configures the table view used to display systems.
private func configureTableView() {
    guard let navigationBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height else { fatalError("Invalid height for navigation bar") }
    let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    let totalHeight = navigationBarHeight + statusBarHeight
    view.insertSubview(tableView, aboveSubview: noSystemsLabel)
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: totalHeight).isActive = true
    tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Everything looks good here:

[image]

Then, I rotate my device and the separators don't span the width of the table view Also, when I scroll the table view, the top cells get cut off before they reach the navigation bar:

[image]

After rotating back into portrait, the table view seems to be taller, causing the top cells to get cut off:

[image]

I have tried using this following method with varying solutions, such as reconfiguring the constraints inside of the animation of the `coordinator`, but I just can't figure out how to get it working correctly:

```swift
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

I have tried to figure out how to use this method, but I guess I am not really understanding it.

How can I configure Auto Layout with my table view so that it is appropriately sized and positioned when rotating the device?

## **Updated**

In response to Aerows answer, I am still getting weird results after implementing the proposed solution:

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

## **Update - Working Solution**

Following Aerow's advice, I used `topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor`, which solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `top constraint` of your `tableView` to the `topLayoutGuide` of your `view` instead.

```
tableView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true
```

The reason is that the `constant` you set in the `top constraint` is right in **portrait mode**, but in **landscape mode** the height of the **status bar** is not the same (`0.f` instead of `20.f`).

If the `navigationBar` in your examples is handled automatically, then the `topLayoutGuide` will always be at the top of the visible `view`.

As for the `cells`, this might be due to how your `tableView` handles `separators` and `insets`. Try setting the background color of the `tableView` or a `cell` to a solid and see if expands the whole `view` or not.

Here is the complete code I ran to verify this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tableView = UITableView(frame: view.frame, style: .Plain)

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor() // For visualisation
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)

    tableView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true
    tableView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor).active = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor).active = true
    tableView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor).active = true
}
```

Comment: I implemented your solution, but this causes the table view to remain under the navigation bar at all times.

Comment: Do you also add the `navigation bar` manually, or is this inherited from a `navigationController`?

Comment: The `navigationBar` is inherited from a `UINavigationController` in Interface Builder.

Comment: I see, same as in my implementation. I've seen other examples where `topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor` is used, maybe this will help?

Comment: Using `topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor` solved it! Thank you very much for your time and working solution! If you want to edit your answer, then I will gladly accept is at the solution.

Comment: Great! I now see in my implementation, the `tableView` was __grouped__ and therefore looked like it was positioned under the `navigationBar` due to its _top padding_. I'll edit my answer.